# Control of the square of 2 at the JVM level?

Tags: java

Could not solve a question. Squared 2 by shifting in Java? is not it ? How do I control?

```
Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
boolean square=false;
int number =scanner.nextInt() ;
        
 while (number != 1 ){

if(number % 2 == 1){
System.out.println("İs not");
square=false;
break;
}else{
square=true;
}
number=(number/2);
}

if(square) {
System.out.println("Square");
}else{
System.out.println("Not Square");
}
   }
```

Comment: This question has many problems.  It's not clear what it is that you're trying to do, or if your code succeeds in doing it.  In addition, you haven't formatted your code correctly.  Proper bracing and indentation is the *first* thing you should do, not the last.

Comment: For guidance on how to improve your question, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: "Powers" of 2 by shifting? `for (int i = 0, p = 1; i < 31; i++) { System.out.printf("%d %s%n", p <<= 1, Integer.toBinaryString(p)); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean powerOfTwo=false;
        
        Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number for cheching it is power of two :");
        
        int number=scanner.nextInt(); 
        
        while(number!=1) {
            
            if(number %2 == 1) {
                powerOfTwo=false;
                break;
                
            }else {
                powerOfTwo=true;
            }
            //Shifting  
        number=number>>1;   
        
        
        }
        isPowerOfTwo(powerOfTwo);
    }
    
    
    private static void isPowerOfTwo(boolean powerOfTwo) {
        if(powerOfTwo) {
            System.out.println("Power of Two");
        }else {
            System.out.println("İs not");
        }
    }
```